# Search Query pass several arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok so far i have this search query:

```
if Object.const_get(params[:model]).find(params[:id]) == @current_department
    sent = Message.where(sender_username: params[:username], recipient_username:  params[:username])
    recieved = Message.where(recipient_username:  params[:username])
end
```

Now i want to change the `recieved`-search query a little bit:

```
 recieved = Message.where(recipient_username: params[:username])
```

To something like:

```
 Message.where(sender_username: @current_department.employees.each { |f| f.username}, recipient_username: params[:username]}
```

But somehow i cannot pass several usernames to the search:

```
sender_username: @current_department.employees.each { |f| f.username}
```

I dont get a error, but my search query is nevertheless not working correctly! How do i have to change my query? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `.map` instead of the each, the map returns an array of the returned value in the block, the each only iterates on each element of the array:

```
sender_username: @current_department.employees.map{ |f| f.username }
```

**The shorthand** (don't use it if ruby <= 1.8.7):

```
sender_username: @current_department.employees.map(&:username)
```

Also, a little improvement, **use pluck** (which is a SQL select):

```
sender_username: @current_department.employees.pluck(:username)
```

`pluck(:username)` will select only the username column of the table and translate it in Ruby objects. Whereas `map(&:username)` will load each records in ruby records and then select only the username attribute).

Comment: `.pluck` is nice but! Is there some way to get ActiveRecord to merge the actual queries? `username IN (SELECT username FROM ... WHERE ...)`? MySQL (at least) won't optimize that much, but at least it's just one hit.

Answer (score 1):

`.map{|f| f.username}`

`.each{}` returns the input list; you want the list of usernames. ActiveRecord will translate the latter into `username IN ("blah", "blah", "blah")`